# ListBox selections not getting updated on postback Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

In my application I have a ListView that shows data with a few different columns. I want to give user flexibility to choose columns they want to see in the ListView. So in my page, I have added following

```
<div class="ibox-content">
        <div id="modal-form" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 b-r">
                                <h3 class="m-t-none m-b">Choose Columns</h3>
                                <p>Move columns from Available to Selected List box to show in the list below</p>
                                <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                                    <label class="control-label-custom" for="lblAvailableColumns">Available Columns</label>
                                    <asp:ListBox class="form-control" Style="height: 150px;" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lbAvailableColumns" runat="server" placeholder="AvailableColumns" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 45px; margin-bottom: 5px" class="form-group col-md-1">
                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="left" value="<" />
                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="right" value=">" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                                    <label class="control-label-custom" for="lblSelectedColumns">Selected Columns</label>
                                    <asp:ListBox class="form-control" Style="height: 150px;" ID="lbSelectedColumns" runat="server" placeholder="SelectedColumns" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                                </div>
                                <div style="text-align: left;" class="form-group  col-md-8">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnApplyChooseColumns" TabIndex="4" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="lnkBtnApplyChooseColumns_Click">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-white"></i> Apply </asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is launched like this

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" href="../#modal-form"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>Choose Columns</a>
```

It looks like this while running
[image]

Though when Apply button is pressed, I dont see updated selections in lbSelectedColumns list box in the codebehind file. What im doing wrong here?

P.S: I think since I am showing this choose columns as a modal dialog using href, that is what is causing the issue. Any solution to this??

Comment: Would placing it in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` help?

Comment: nope, it does not help

Comment: It may look a silly question, but are the ListBoxes inside the form?

Comment: no they are not.. when I added them in a form, I was not able to postback..

Comment: in your form_load, is your (page initialization / data loading) code inside of a `if (! page.ispostback())` block?

Comment: I do have `if(! Page.IsPostBack)` condition present in Page_Load() but when `Apply` button is pressed, its a post back that occurs, so the else part is executed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your `Page_Load` so we can see what the "else" part is that's being executed.

Comment: yes you need to post code, not html if your asking a asp.net question

Comment: If i dont show this dialog as modal ... just show hide a div including all the above.. then it all works fine. since I am using href to show the modal dialog.. that is what is causing the issue..